# grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation problem - secured plugin is not resolving

Tags: spring-security, annotations, grails-3.1, netbeans-8.1

I used grails 3.1.X in NetBeans 8.1.
Secured plugin is not resolving wen a used annotation. Code below:

```
package securityplugintest
//import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured //not esolved 

@Secured(['ROLE_USER'])   //not resolved 
class ProductAnnouncementController {


 def index() {
  def announcements = ProductAnnouncement.createCriteria().list {
        order("dateCreated", "desc")
        maxResults(1)
    }
    render announcements.first()?.message
    //render announcements.any()?.meassage
    
  }
}
```

In NetBeans I have configured Grails 3.1.11, and `spring-security` plugin as

```
dependencies {
 compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3'
}
```

I am following [this manual](http://sergiodelamo.es/how-to-use-spring-security-core-to-secure-you-grails-3-app/) and getting error for the last step.

Comment: Can you please add what error you are getting?

Comment: Can you please change your plugin to `compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'` and compile it once added.

Comment: Yes it works !!!     //compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.3'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1'
}
but "import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured"  has red underline ))) System NetBeans hint message: unable to resolve class grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

Comment: @AlexTitov If my answer has solved your issue then you can accept it by clicking the green tick on the left side of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well First thing you should add plugin `compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1` under the `build.gradle` .
I have just given you the different plugin version than that of you are using nothing more.

Second thing you should compile your project after adding the plugin.

This should do the trick for you.

But as you have stated that you are getting the `red line` under the `import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured` after above steps.

Please follow the below step :

As stated in the `Grails 3` docs ->

> To use annotations, specify `securityConfigType="Annotation"` , or
>   leave it unspecified because it’s the default:
>
> Specifying securityConfigType as “Annotation”
>   `grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = "Annotation"`

In your case please try to specify it.

And before running the app please clean -> compile -> run your app.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your plugin to compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1' and compile it once added. – Prakash Thete